# toUpperCase() para convertir en mayúsculas hasta encontrar un punto

Tags: javascript

Me piden diseñar un código que logre convertir caracteres a mayúsculas hasta encontrar un punto, solo los caracteres previos *al primer punto* el resto se quedan en minúsculas, debo mostrar en consola el antes y el después.

Mi código:

```
const str = 'hola.mundo!';
console.log(str);
console.log(str.toUpperCase());
```

He intentado con *for*, *if* y la sentencia *break*, pero no logro hacer que funcione

Answer (score 8):

Yo haría un split con criterio '.' para dividir la cadena en un array. Después, haz el toUpperCase sobre el primer elemento del array, y después vuelve a unirlos separados por el punto. Ej:

```js
    var str = 'hola.mundo!';
    
    var str_array = str.split('.');
    str_array[0] = str_array[0].toUpperCase();
    
    str = '';
    str_array.forEach(unir);
    
    function unir(item, index){
        if(str != '') str += '.';
        str += item;
    }
    
    console.log(str); // "HOLA.mundo!"
```

Este código sirve aun si hay más puntos. Espero que sea de ayuda.
Un saludo.

Comment: En lugar del ciclo para unir los elementos puedes usar [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Por lo demás, buena respuesta. +1

Answer (score 6):

Aquí tienes una solución con expresiones regulares.
Se trata de encontrar una cadena hasta un punto (que incluya letras en minúscula, mayúscula o espacios).

Los paréntesis en la expresión regular indican grupos que luego puedes referenciar por su índice.

```js
const regex = /^([a-zA-Z ]*)(\..*)/g;
const str = `hola caracola.mundo!`;
let m;
m = regex.exec(str);

console.log(m[1].toUpperCase() + m[2]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Puedes dividir tu cadena en dos partes con `split()` y luego imprimir la primera parte (que estará en el índice `0`) en mayúsculas.

Algo así:

```js
const str = 'hola.mundo!';
const separator='.';
const parts=str.split(separator);
console.log(`${parts[0].toUpperCase()}${separator}${parts[1]}`);
```

#### Posibilidad de repetición del separador

Si hay posibilidad de que el separador se repita varias veces y sólo interese poner en mayúscula la primera ocurrencia antes del separador, puedes hacerlo mediante `substring()` combinado con `indexOf()`.

Cabe decir que esta solución puede aplicar para cualquier caso, y suele ser más rápida desde el punto de vista del rendimiento que usando expresiones regulares o `split`.

```js
let str="hola.mundo.con.más.puntos.año.2022";
let separator=".";
let upperPart=str.substring(0, str.indexOf(separator)).toUpperCase(); 
let lowerPart=str.substring(str.indexOf(separator) + 1); 
console.log(`${upperPart}${separator}${lowerPart}`);
```

Comment: @Marcos gracias por el apunte, he añadido al final una solución para esos casos.